# Openpyxl not writing a multiline output from BeautifulSoup to cell

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I am having an issue with openpyxl and writing a multiline output from BeautifulSoup.

When I `print (parsed_links)` the output from BeautifulSoup it looks like this:

```
Link1
Link2
Link3
Link4
```

When I write the same data that prints fine to a cell using openpyxl,
I only get the last line entered in the cell.

```
Link4
```

I am using this code:

```
current_db.cell(row=2, column=4).value = (parsed_links)
```

Any advice on how I can write the entire BeautifulSoup output Link1, Link2, Link3, Link4 to one cell or each to its own cell? I know using csv I could use writerow but I want to do this in openpyxl to avoid more dependencies.

```
`#4CHAN THREADS LOG

from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


#XLSX DATABASE MAP

main_db = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/chanlog/db.xlsx')
current_db = main_db["current"]


#URL MAP

go_to_page = 'https://thebarchive.com/b/page/7'


#START CHROME

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")


#GO TO 4CHAN NAVI PAGE LOAD ALL THREADS INTO XLSX
time.sleep(2)
browser.get(go_to_page)
time.sleep(4)


#PARSE THREAD URLS FROM PAGES
pages_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
for mobile_view in pages_soup.find_all(class_='mobile_view'):
    for thread_links in mobile_view.find_all('a'):
        parsed_thread_links = (thread_links.get('href'))
        links = str(parsed_thread_links)
        for row, text in enumerate(links.split('\n'), start=2):
                current_db.cell(row=row, column=4).value = text
                main_db.save('C:/chanlog/db.xlsx')
                print(parsed_thread_links)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help to get you going:

```
import requests
import openpyxl     
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://thebarchive.com/b/page/7', headers=headers)
pages_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
row = 2

for mobile_view in pages_soup.find_all(class_='mobile_view'):
    for thread_link in mobile_view.find_all('a', href=True):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=4).value = thread_link['href']
        row += 1

wb.save('db.xlsx')
```

For each HREF that is found, just increment the row number. Note, chromedriver is not needed to get this information and should be a lot quicker if you can avoid using it.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a working example with the URL you are using, I would then be able to recreate your problem and help better.

Comment: I have updated as requested. It requires chromedriver.exe to run. It’s still only writing the one LINK4 entry into the first cell, like before and is still printing correctly LINK1,LINK2,LINK3,LINK4. Is it possible the line breaks provided by the Beautiful Soup’s (parsed_thread_links) is not a single string containing newlines?

Comment: Ok, you only actually get 1 href at a time, so all that is needed is to increment a row counter each time. Also, `requests` can be used without needing a chromedriver.

Comment: That issue makes sense to me now, being that I was only getting a single href at a time. Your advice has completely solved my issue. Thank you